# Datepicker Is showing on the back of fancy box

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using datepicker in jquery but the problem is when I click on date picker is shows behind the fancy box .

The code is like this.

```
<div class="fancybox-overlay fancybox-overlay-fixed" id="copytimesheetdiv"
    style="width: auto; height: auto; display: block;">
    <div
        class="fancybox-wrap fancybox-desktop fancybox-opened"
        tabindex="-1"
        style="width: 458px; height: auto; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 445px; opacity: 1; overflow: visible;margin-top:250px;">
        <div class="fancybox-skin"
            style="padding: 15px; width: auto; height: auto;">
            <div class="fancybox-outer">
                <div class="fancybox-inner"
                    style="overflow: auto; width: 428px; height: 100px; cursor: pointer;">

                    <div class="mid_section">
                        <!--right section-->

                        <div align="left">

                            **<input type="text" id="copyt"/>** // this is the text box on whose click datepicker is called.

                        </div>
                           <div style="margin-top: 20px">
                     <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="cancelCopy" class="button closeFancybox" value= "Cancel">

                      <input type="button" value="Ok" id="ok" class="button closeFancybox" style="align : right">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also adjusted the Z  element of datepicker but nothing worked .

Comment: can you show us fiddle and js code

Comment: Hello susheel  , I have basically used the js from following link  :-   Website: http://www.datejs.com/ or http://www.coolite.com/datejs/     Thank u